# Finding all solutions for to the equation $x^3 = 0\ {\rm mod}\ 9$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How do I go about finding the solutions to:

$$ x^3 = 0\mod 9 $$

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: If $x^3$ is divisible by $9$, what follows about $x$?

Comment: Try out some: $x=0$, $x=1$, $x=2$, $x=3$, $x=4$. Wich are okay? Any idea why?

Comment: Well how about trying each of the nine possible residues! Duh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$0^3 = 0[9]$

$1^3 = 1[9]$

$2^3 = 8[9]$

$3^3 = 0[9]$

$4^3 = 1[9]$

$5^3 = 8[9]$

$6^3 = 0[9]$

$7^3 = 1[9]$

$8^3 = 8[9]$

so your solution will be  $x = 3n$ such that $n= 0, 1, 2, ...$

Comment: is that a proof?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** write $x = 3^p y$ with $3\nmid y$.

Answer (score 0):

$9$ divided $x^3$, thus $3$ divides $x^3$. By [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) we find that $3$ divides $x$, thus we can define $x=3t$ and this is our solution.